# How to correctly make return button in Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created a side panel with buttons. On click I load specific php file assigned to each button. How to correctly add functionality that will return us to the default button list?

HTML:

```
<div class="sidemenu">
    <div class="content">
        <button data-content="first">Load first content</button>
        <button data-content="second">Load second content</button>
        <button data-content="third">Load third content</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $( '.sidemenu button' ).on('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var content = $( this ).data( 'content' );

        $( '.sidemenu .content' ).empty();

        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { 
                action: 'sidemenu_content',
                content: content,
            },
            success: function( result) {
                $( '.sidemenu .content' ).append( result );
                console.log(result);

            }
        });

    });
});
```

PHP:

```
function sidemenu_content() {
if( isset( $_GET['content'] ) ) {
    $content= $_GET['content'];
    if ( $content == 'first' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/sidemenu/first.php' );
    } elseif ( $content == 'second' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/sidemenu/second.php' );
    } elseif ( $content == 'third' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/sidemenu/third.php' );
    }
}
wp_die();
}
```

I tried to add `<button data-content="return">Return</button>` in each of three php files and in the `sidemenu_content` function:

```
if ( $content == 'return' ) {
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/sidemenu/return.php' );
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

Almost everything works with this code. "Return" button appear but onclick doesn't really return to the button list.

```
var backup;
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $('.sidemenu button').on('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var content = $( this ).data( 'content' );
        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { 
                action: 'sidemenu_content',
                content: content,
            },
            success: function( result) {
                backup = $( '.sidemenu .content' ).innerHTML;
                $( '.sidemenu .content' ).innerHTML = result;
                $( '.sidemenu .content' ).empty();
                $( '.sidemenu .content' ).append( '<button class="return">Return</button>' + result );
                $( '.sidemenu button.return').on('click', function( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $( '.sidemenu .content' ).innerHTML = backup;
                })
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's good for performance if when clicked on return button browser doesn't send AJAX to get already have code. I add hidden block to backup buttons for reuse after click on return

```
<div class="sidemenu">
    <div class="content">
        <button data-content="first">Load first content</button>
        <button data-content="second">Load second content</button>
        <button data-content="third">Load third content</button>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $('.sidemenu button').on('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var content = $( this ).data( 'content' );
        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { 
                action: 'sidemenu_content',
                content: content,
            },
            success: function( result) {
                $( '.sidemenu .hidden' ).append($( '.sidemenu .content button' ));
                $( '.sidemenu .content' ).html(result);
                $( '.sidemenu .content' ).append('<button class="return">Return</button>');
                $('.sidemenu button.return').on('click', function( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $( '.sidemenu .content' ).empty();
                    $( '.sidemenu .content' ).append($( '.sidemenu .hidden button' ));
                })
            }
        })
    })
});
```

How it Works:
Before empty all data I backupped and after successfull ajax response I empty data end append response data. After response data I append return button. If you click this button all data in `.content` empty and append backupped code. 
P.S You can optimize this code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copied and pasted your code, but it doesn't seem to work for me. After clicking my buttons, "Return" button appears, the others don't hide and assigned content doesn't load. I'm trying to modify the code but I have problems with it.  I updated my question. Can you look at this?

Comment: @Avigo, I'm sorry for first code. I mixed up Jquery and JS...